# Define array of file locations, parse and replace. Where's my error?

Tags: php, arrays, replace

I'm trying to define an array with a list of file urls, and then have each file parsed and if a predefined string is found, for that string to be replaced. For some reason what I have isn't working, I'm not sure what's incorrect:

```
<?php

$htF = array('/home/folder/file.extension', '/home/folder/file.extension', '/home/folder/file.extension', '/home/folder/file.extension', '/home/folder/file.extension');

function update() {
global $htF;
$handle = fopen($htF, "r");
if ($handle) {
     $previous_line = $content = '';
     while (!feof($handle)) {
          $current_line = fgets($handle);

          if(stripos($previous_line,'PREDEFINED SENTENCE') !== FALSE)
          {
               $output = shell_exec('URL.COM');
               if(preg_match('#([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}#',$output,$matches))
               {
                    $content .= 'PREDEFINED SENTENCE '.$matches[0]."\n";
               }
          }else{
               $content .= $current_line;
          }
          $previous_line = $current_line;
     }
     fclose($handle);

     $tempFile = tempnam('/tmp','allow_');
     $fp = fopen($tempFile, 'w');
     fwrite($fp, $content);
     fclose($fp);
     rename($tempFile,$htF);
     chown($htF,'admin');
     chmod($htF,'0644');
}
}
array_walk($htF, 'update');
?>
```

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: @knittl What do you mean? I dont think I used the protocol in urls did i?

Comment: oh… my bad. I misunderstood, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Do you have permissions to open the file?
- Do you have permissions to write to /tmp ?
- Do you have permissions to write to the destination file or folder?
- Do you have permissions to chown?
- Have you checked your regex? Try something like http://regexpal.com/ to see if it's valid.

Try adding error messages or throw Exceptions for all of the fail conditions for these.

Comment: I forgot to include that I ran the script through SSH and it returned No such file or directorys/file.extension: line 1: ?php
/home/folder/file.extension: line 2: //: is a directory
/home/folder/file.extension: line 3: //: is a directory
/home/folder/file.extension: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/home/folder/file.extension: line 4: `$htF = array('/home/folder/file.extension', '/home/folder/file.extension', '/home/folder/file.extension', '/home/folder/file.extension')

Comment: Your error is therefore before line 4, which is something you apparently haven't pasted because the line `$htF = array( etc )` looks fine to me. Syntax errors mean that there is some sort of error with the basic syntax of your file and has nothing at all to do with any of the errors I mentioned above.

Comment: Also, if `/home/folder/file.extension` doesn't exist, your script won't work either. You need to create this file.

Comment: Sorry, Line 1 is <?php line 2-3 are comments i omitted, and like 4 is the start of the array definition.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, if ANY of the deifined files/urls are not in existance, then the entire script fails?  How would I go about having the script perform function on array members with valid files, and to just skip array elements that dont?

Comment: You need to do what I said in my answer and add error messages. For example look into `file_exists()`, `is_file()`, `is_readable()`, `is_writable()`. Add successes and failures to your code so you can pinpoint what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

there's this line:

```
 if(stripos($previous_line,'PREDEFINED SENTENCE') !== FALSE)
```

and I think you just want a != in there. Yes?

Comment: no. stripos may return `0` (beginning of string) which is `== FALSE`, but not `=== FALSE` (not found). type comparison is very important here

Answer (score 0):

You're using `$htF` within the update function as global, which means you're trying to `fopen()` an array.

```
$fh = fopen($htF, 'r');
```

is going to get parsed as

```
$fh = fopen('Array', 'r');
```

and return false, unless you happen to have a file named 'Array'.

You've also not specified any parameters for your function, so array_walk cannot pass in the array element it's dealing with at the time.

Comment: So how would I go about fixing this?

Comment: `function update($htF) { ... } ` and remove the global definition from within the function. That lets arraywalk pass in its current array element.